# Changing reference to Listbox to add item

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I've got userform with multiple listboxes inside and a button for adding item.
[it looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvYX6.jpg)
When user click a button he can select the listbox by name and add new event (it's now static typed). When user tries to save it code will call the function which should change reference to listbox in which new item should be added and created.

I see the draft like this but I don't know how to handle this listboxnames (see comments):

```
Function AddItemToListbox(listBoxName as String)
    Select case listBoxName
        case listBoxName1
            'here I'd like to set listbox
            'something like set listbox=listBox1
        case listBoxName2
            'here I'd like to set listbox
        case listBoxName3
            'here I'd like to set listbox
        case listBoxName4
            'here I'd like to set listbox
        End Select

listbox.addItem

'and do the other stuff with this listbox which I need to do

End Function
```

Do you have solution or reference to materials wehre it can be explained?

Comment: Instead of passing the `ListBoxName` as a `String` why not just pass the `ListBox`?

Comment: Also, in your example it doesn't look like there is anyway to select which `ListBox` you want to add it to

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for anserw. After pressing button "add event" the new userform appears where user can select which listbox (by name) he will choose (I used checkboxes described with names so I can get String from it). How can I refer to the listboxes there? It will be much easier to passing listBoxes but I can't imagine how to do it..

Comment: From the new userform how do you pass the inputs back to the parent userform?

Comment: So I need to pass all the listBoxes to child userform, let user to choose one, and pass back the chosen listBox back to parent form in another function written in parent userform called from the child userform?

Comment: Have a look at my update as well. This uses the `Label` captions in your parent `UserForm` instead of using `Control` names which will mean nothing to the end user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally this is how I would approach it with my two forms

My main form is called `UserForm1` and my 'Event Picker' is called `EventPicker`

`UserForm1` is set up as your example

[image: UserForm1]

and `EventPicker` shows

[image: EventPicker]

Behind my `UserForm1` I have the following code

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ctrl
    Dim Eventfrm As EventPicker

    Set Eventfrm = New EventPicker
    Set Eventfrm.ParentForm = Me

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "ListBox" Then
            Eventfrm.NamePickerCombo.AddItem ctrl.Name
        End If
    Next ctrl

    Eventfrm.Show
End Sub
```

This is called on `Click` of the 'Add Event' button and initiates the `EventPicker` form by populating the `ComboBox` and setting the `ParentForm` property so that the child form knows where it has come from.

Behind my `EventPicker` form I then have the following code

```
Option Explicit
Private vParentForm As UserForm1
Public Property Set ParentForm(v As UserForm1)
    Set vParentForm = v
End Property
Public Property Get ParentForm() As UserForm1
    Set ParentForm = vParentForm
End Property
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lBox As MSForms.ListBox

    Set lBox = ParentForm.Controls(Me.NamePickerCombo.Value)
    lBox.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Value

    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Leaving me with the following

[image: Result]

Update for using Names instead of control `Name`s.

Behind `UserForm1`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ctrl
    Dim Eventfrm As EventPicker

    Set Eventfrm = New EventPicker
    Set Eventfrm.ParentForm = Me

    Debug.Print Me.Name, TypeName(Me)

    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Debug.Print ctrl.Name, TypeName(ctrl)
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
            Eventfrm.NamePickerCombo.AddItem ctrl.Caption
        End If
    Next ctrl

    Eventfrm.Show
End Sub
```

Behind `EventPicker`

```
Option Explicit
Private vParentForm As UserForm1
Public Property Set ParentForm(v As UserForm1)
    Set vParentForm = v
End Property
Public Property Get ParentForm() As UserForm1
    Set ParentForm = vParentForm
End Property
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim lBox As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim lbl As MSForms.Label
    Dim ctrl As Control

    Debug.Print Me.NamePickerCombo.Value, Me.TextBox1.Value

    For Each ctrl In ParentForm.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "Label" Then
            If ctrl.Caption = Me.NamePickerCombo.Value Then
                Set lbl = ctrl
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next ctrl

    For Each ctrl In ParentForm.Controls
        If ctrl.Left >= lbl.Left And ctrl.Left + ctrl.Width <= lbl.Left + lbl.Width Then
            Set lBox = ctrl
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ctrl

    lBox.AddItem Me.TextBox1.Value

    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

[image: Results 2]

Comment: Thank you very much! This was really helpful!